# Optimize stored-procedure T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, query-optimization

I need to optimize my t-sql query somehow but i do not have much experience in it. Hope on your support. The execution of it lasts to long if I pass many RetailersID into where condition. Apparently I have to rewrite the sub-query in the first

```
Select LeadRetailerId, Count(*) as NumberGreenLeads
from  [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact] a
inner join [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivity] b
on a.UID = b.ContactUID
where 1=1
    AND b.LeadStatusDate > DATEADD(Year, -1, GetDate())
    AND a.LeadRetailerId in (@RetailerId)
    group by a.LeadRetailerId


Select Table_1.LeadRetailerId, Table_1.EscalationLevel ,Count(Table_1.EscalationLevel) as Number
from (
    select a.LeadRetailerId, max(EscalationLevel) as EscalationLevel
    from [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact]  a
    inner join [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivityEscalationHistory] b
    on b.ContactUID = a.UID
    where 1=1
    AND a.LeadRetailerId in (@RetailerId) 
    group by ContactUID, LeadRetailerId) as Table_1
Group by EscalationLevel, LeadRetailerId
```

Comment: For starters, you can remove (1=1) in both places, although SSMS presumably does this behind the scenes anyway ....

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking the value `DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE())` and putting it in a variable, which will simplify that part of the join. Also, a depending on the number of values in @RetailerId, that could be put into a table variable or similar to aid its use in querying. I would then display the actual execution plan and see if any indexes are recommended as missing.

Comment: `depending on the number of values in @RetailerId` ?? By definition there can be only 1 value in there.

Comment: Granted, that it can only take a single string value, but that string appears to be used to hold several values, given the `in (@RetailerId)` syntax.

Comment: It is confusing indeed... The recurring conundrum about what it is that the user actually wants, what he asked for and what he eventually got =)

Answer (score 0):

Each of these queries can be turned into indexed views with a little cleanup (e.g. `COUNT` will need to become `COUNT_BIG`.)

For the first query, however, you can't have the GETDATE() expression and index the view. For that you would have to create a table called something like dbo.LastYear with a single row that contains the previous year; we'll call it *Yr*. Then can replace:

```
AND b.LeadStatusDate > DATEADD(Year, -1, GetDate())
```

With:

```
JOIN dbo.LastYear AS ly ON b.LeadStatusDate = ly.Yr
```

If these tables are in a high-transaction environment then an indexed view might not be an option; make sure to test, test. The dbo.LastYear table would obviously need to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked the first query a bit to this (for readability)

```
SELECT LeadRetailerId, Count(*) as NumberGreenLeads
  FROM  [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact] a
 INNER JOIN [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivity] b
         ON b.ContactUID = a.UID
        AND b.LeadStatusDate > DATEADD(Year, -1, GetDate())
 WHERE a.LeadRetailerId in (@RetailerId)
 GROUP BY a.LeadRetailerId
```

Although the order of things has changed, MSSQL will (most probably) execute the same query plan. The first thing I notice is that you have `a.LeadRetailerId in (@RetailerId)` in the query. Do you plan on adding extra values or is it just this one? Having multiple values in the one variable will not work as you might think then, which some simple experimentation should quickly show.
If you will only use the 1 value, you can replace the `IN` with `=`, and you can simplify the query to

```
SELECT LeadRetailerId = @RetailerId, 
       Count(*) as NumberGreenLeads
  FROM [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact] a
 INNER JOIN [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivity] b
         ON b.ContactUID = a.UID
        AND b.LeadStatusDate > DATEADD(Year, -1, GetDate())
 WHERE a.LeadRetailerId = @RetailerId
```

which might be a bit faster.

Going by your description I'm however thinking you're using something along this:

```
SELECT LeadRetailerId, Count(*) as NumberGreenLeads
  FROM  [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact] a
 INNER JOIN [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivity] b
         ON b.ContactUID = a.UID
        AND b.LeadStatusDate > DATEADD(Year, -1, GetDate())
 WHERE a.LeadRetailerId in (@RetailerId1, @RetailerId2, @RetailerId3, @RetailerId4, @RetailerId5, etc)
 GROUP BY a.LeadRetailerId
```

where the list grows 'as needed'.
If this is getting slow quickly you might check if you have any indexes on the tables that can help out MSSQL with finding a fast way to process this. Ideally you'd have an index on`a.LeadRetailerId` that includes `a.UID` on the first table, and another one on the other table on `b.ContactUID` and `b.LeadStatusDate`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[Contact] (LeadRetailerId) INCLUDE (UID)
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivity] (ContactUID, LeadStatusDate)
```

Keep in mind that this will speed up this query will take extra space in the database and will create some overhead when `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE`-ing on the table. (no such thing as a free lunch etc, although I wouldn't worry too about it right now, the benefit of indexes often outweighs there overhead... when used sensibly =)

The second query is a bit strange in that you do a `GROUP BY b.ContactUID`. I'm not familiar with your table-structure but are you sure the outcome of said query is what you want? Anyway, if it is, it should benefit from the same proposed index on the first table. For the third table I'd suggest:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test ON [MBCH_LMT].[lead].[ContactActivityEscalationHistory] (ContactUID, EscalationLevel)
```

One of the things to keep in mind with SQL is that the system will interpret your query and come up with an execution plan which it deems the most optimal. This plan depends not only on your query, but also on the availability of indexes, the amount and types of data in the tables and sometimes some black magic =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are the victim of Parameter Sniffing in stored procs.
Believe it or not, it's a huge deal (read on it someday), but might be very easy to solve.

If you have @RetailerId in your query, you only have to make a local parameter in your query.

```
declare @_RetailerId  bigint
set @_RetailerId = @RetailerId  -- the one you pass from your stored proc parameters.
```

You might be surprised. The queryplan is now totally different.

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts,

1) Instead of `Count(*)`, you could also write `Count(1)` --May not make big difference though

2) You could replace second `Inner Join` with `Where Exists`. Exists are faster in some cases when compared to Join

3) As rightly mentioned, parameter sniffing makes big difference.

4) You could also try creating #Table where you could do indexing for large record count.

5) If rows is not big or huge, consider re-writing your query with CTE (Common table Expression) in that case you don't need to do step 4.

Hope it helps.